# how to make form update while function is working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, doevents

I have a function that attempt to connect to a server and post information about the progress and result. but i just found out that while my function is working the application will "freeze" and since the whole connecting thing might take a while the user might think that the application is malfunctioning and try to quit. do you know how to get the function to update form before continuing the rest of function, so the user know the application is working.

```
private void TestConnection()
{
    ResutBoxTable.Controls.Clear();
    ResutBoxTable.RowStyles.Clear();
    PrintResults("Starting connection test...", Color.White);
    ImapClient client = new ImapClient(IncAddressTxt.Text, true, certificateCheckbox.Checked);
    if (client.Connect())
    {
        PrintResults("Connection to incoming mail server succesful!",Color.Green );
        PrintResults("Attempting to Login to incoming mail server...", Color.White);
        if (client.Login(UserTxt.Text,PasswordTxt.Text))
        {
            PrintResults("Login to incoming mail server succesful succesfull!",Color.Green);
        }
        else
        {
            PrintResults("Failed to login to incoming mail server!", Color.Red);
            PrintResults("Please check your login information and try agian.", Color.Red);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        PrintResults("Failed to connect to incoming mail server!", Color.Red);
        PrintResults("Please check your connection prameters and try again.", Color.Red);
    }
    PrintResults("Testing connection complete!",Color.White);
}
```

also if your answer has something to do with threading please throw 1 or 2 explanation lines as i only know threading theoretically and never used it myself.
thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your application is freezing is cause everything is running on the UI thread. If you separate your busy function to a separate thread, the freezing won't occur.

Use [Background Worker Threads](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) to accomplish this.
Another great example: [Background thread for beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)

---

Used the second links example as source

```
    BackgroundWorker m_oWorker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_oWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        // Create a background worker thread that ReportsProgress &
        // SupportsCancellation
        // Hook up the appropriate events.
        m_oWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(m_oWorker_DoWork);

        //optional progress indicators
        m_oWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler
                (m_oWorker_ProgressChanged);
        m_oWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    void m_oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Run your primary function
        TestConnection();

        //Progress indicator - optional
        m_oWorker.ReportProgress(100);
    }
    //optional
    void m_oWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Report progress

    }
```

Also, as a side note, you need to make **PrintResults** Thread friendly or use the Invoke/BeginInvoke hack.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how would i for example put this block of code into a thread??? i saw that kind of tutorials before but when i try to put my code into a thread like those they won't work at all, and yes i do make sure to include the using.

Comment: @soorena12 Is this a WPF or Forms project?

Comment: no it's a normal form application in C#, does the term WPF also apply to C#?

Comment: @soorena12 There aren't any "normal" windows application. Its commonly one of the following: WinForms, WPF, or console. I'm assuming since it has a GUI, its either WinForms or WPF.

Comment: surprisingly i didn't know there were a WPF for C# as well, no it's WInForm